# JPA validation problem: Entity 'X' has no Id or EmbeddedId

Tags: eclipse, jpa

Which, I couldn't quite figure out why Eclipse Galileo's JPA validator would say so, as my class 'X' clearly had an @Id annotation on the primary key "uniqueId". The error would disappear if I commented out the @Basic annotation line, but that didn't quite make sense. Anyway, attaching snippet below from memory:

```
@Entity
class X {
...
@Id
@Basic(optional=false)
@Column(name="someUniqueId", unique=false)
String uniqueId;
...
}
```

Is this a bug, or is there a JPA standard which I'm not aware of on the use of annotations?

Answer (score 1):

You have here a [similar case](http://www.coderanch.com/t/445280/Object-Relational-Mapping/java/Error-Entity-name-has-no#1981489) which may suggest a case or type issue.

But as [mentioned here](http://markmail.org/message/smdxaugfhm6batq7), I would rather bet on [bug 217192](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=217192) (which can be comared with the "non-[bug" 208249](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=208249))

You can also specify which version of eclipse and Dali JPA Tool you are using.

Comment: Eclipse 3.5 Galileo, and Dali 2.2. Seems bug #217192 isn't the same as mine, as it only applies to subclasses inheriting IDs. I'll probably file a new bug after this. :P

Comment: @Jerry Good idea. You can also post it here, and select your answer as the official one if you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
@EmbeddedId
String uniqueId;
```

Answer (score 0):

You annotated the "uniqueId" with "unique=false".
This could be the root because IDs have to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a `@Basic` annotation as `@Id` already restricts the attribute's type (as defined by the spec) and the only information `@Basic` can add are settings for `fetch` and `optional` both of which make no sense for a primary key (i.e. a primary key must have `fetch=EAGER` and `optional=false`).